# How Many Features Are Used in Random Forest When max_features is not an integer?

Tags: random-forest

In the `RandomForestClassifier` function in `sklearn.ensemble`, one of the parameters is `max_features`, which controls the size of the random subset of features that are considered at each node splitting. I would think this needs to be an integer, since of course the size of a subset needs to be an integer.

But one of the options here is `"log2"`, which sets `max_features` to `log_2(n_features)`.

I was wondering how that works, considering `log_2(n_features)` will not be an integer unless `n_features` is a power of 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for the number of features gets passed down to the `BaseDecisionTree` class. [Looking at the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L263), you can see that the value that is used is calculated by first taking log with base two and then converting it to an integer (i.e. rounding it).

```
if self.max_features == "auto":
    if is_classification:
        max_features = max(1, int(np.sqrt(self.n_features_)))
    else:
        max_features = self.n_features_
elif self.max_features == "sqrt":
    max_features = max(1, int(np.sqrt(self.n_features_)))
elif self.max_features == "log2":
    max_features = max(1, int(np.log2(self.n_features_)))
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid value for max_features. "
                     "Allowed string values are 'auto', "
                     "'sqrt' or 'log2'.")
```